# Get text of all div with a same class CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I am new in casperJS and, I will appreciate someone telling me how to **scrape** all information with the same css class of a website.
for example, there is a list of items and all items have the same css class,  I want to retrieve all the list.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`casper.getElementsInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo):

```
casper.start('https://www.example.com/', function () {
  var example = this.getElementsInfo('.example');
  this.echo(example[0].text);
});
```